# Can't adjust Controller in gem Devise, ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm having difficulties adjusting the controller in the gem devise. On https://github.com/plataformatec/devise there is a guide to configure controllers:

1. Create your custom controllers using the generator which requires a scope:

   rails generate devise:controllers [scope]

I typed in: `rails generate devise:controllers users`

2. Tell the router to use this controller:

   devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }

I added  `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }` to the routes

3. Copy the views from devise/sessions to users/sessions. Since the controller was changed, it won't use the default views located in devise/sessions.

I created a folder in users called sessions and I copied the views from devise/sessions to users/sessions

4.Finally, change or extend the desired controller actions.

At this point, I should be able to adjust the controller, but nothings happens. For example, when I do this:

registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<% @user.each do |name|%>
    <%= name.username %>
<% end %>
```

users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

#   GET /resource/sign_up
   def new
     @user = User.all
     super
   end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end
```

Nothing happens. Where did I go wrong? You can access the code here: https://github.com/Metaphysiker/philosophica

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are only overriding the routes for sessions - not registrations. Run 'rake routes' in the console to see the mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it looks like you typed:

`rails generate devise:controllers [users]`
users in `[]` so you got a folder called `[users]`
You may want to delete that.

But your actual problem is that you did not move the views to `views/users/session` the folder `views/users` has only a new.erb. Copy the content of `views/devise` to `views/users` and you get what you want.

Aditionaly you should `add devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" , registrations: „users/registrations“ }`
to your routes.rb